# como puedo instalar mi restApi y que funcione en servidor php?

Tags: nodejs, express, cpanel, webapi

He desarrollado una aplicacion usando node y express, la separe en en FrontEnd y BackEnd. La aplicacion la estoy subiendo en un hosting de HostGator, el FrontEnd trabaja perfecto pero el BackEnd para el servicio resulta que no reconoce la ruta a los metodos como si lo hace en el localhost de mi maquina y no se que pueda estar pasando.

La siguiente imagen corresponde al archivo index.js que define todo el el proyecto y arranca el servidor.

[image: Configuracion de la llamada de los métodos en el archivo index.js]

El mensaje de error que me da al tratar de acceder al servicio es el siguiente, no se si tenga que configurar algo especial en el archivo .htaccess del servidor.

[image: No encuentra la ruta]

Aqui esta como esta organizado en las carpetas

[image: Esqueleto del proyecto]

Comment: No creo que lo que quieres hacer funcione correctamente, deberías intentar accediendo por ssh (Si host te lo permite) a ver como te resulta.

Comment: saludos, 
se me permite abrir la terminal sin problemas y hacer todos los cambios o correr lo que yo necesite sobre el servidor. que me recomiendas hacer en la terminal?

Comment: Debes tener habilitado el servicio de VPS o un Dedicated Server, e instalar node en ese servidor para luego correr tu servicio de node y rutear desde tu webserver el dominio al puerto en el que está corriendo este servicio. Si sólo tienes contratado un servicio de hosting te va a ser imposible correr tu código ya que la configuración de ese tipo de servicios sólo corre código escrito en HTML y/o PHP.

Comment: Ya me pude conectar, ahora el lio esta con la BD
{"success":false,"msg":{"code":"ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR","errno":1045,"sqlMessage":"Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)","sqlState":"28000","fatal":true}

Como saco los datos correctos del PHPAdmin, 
no creo que para conectarme el host real sea localHost...